# How to get an object's events ? (ce-html)

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm developing a js application on a CE-HTML browser based television.
So I have limited options and no documents for the browser, but it's modified version of webkit or similar to webkit I assume.

I can use the object tag for videos, but how can I get the events of this object. Is there any way of it? For example finished, buffering etc.

```
<object type="video/mp4" id="myvid" data="myvideo.mp4" width="640" height="480"></object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <![CDATA[
      // check the current playstate of the mediaobject
      function checkPlayState()
      {
      switch (myvid.playState)
      {
        case 5: // finished
           endOfFile();
               break;
         case 0: // stopped
         case 6: // error
         case 1: // playing
         case 2: // paused
         case 3: // connecting
         case 4: // buffering
         default:
           // do nothing
            break;
      }
      }

    myvid.onPlayStateChange=checkPlayState;
    ]]>
</script>
```

Should you still need it;) Hope it helps!
edit:
Of course you need to add breaks and all the code, but here is the way to handle mentioned events it.

Comment: somehow i found it, but thanks anyways, its the correct answer. :)